# Filtering the most recent date only in Excel 2013 Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which contains a list of customer.  Under each customer is a list of dates, currently expanded.  I only want to show the most recent date for each customer.  Is there any way to filter this pivot table to show the single date entry rather than the entire list of dates for each customer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Maximum` function for date value.

Please note that you will likely also have to manually set date format (use `Format` button in bottom-left corner of the window).

If you have other columns that you need to sum - do the same trick as above, but using `Sum` function.

[image: Screen]